# How to fix: CSS animation reset everytime user clicks a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got 3 buttons on my page(male, female, non-gender) that cause the characters to bounce on the page. Currently when the user clicks a second button the first button's characters keep bouncing. How do I make it so only one button's characters bounce?
JavaScript code below:

```js
const allDivs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div'))

const mainHeader = document.querySelector('header')

let maleButton = document.createElement('button')
maleButton.textContent = 'Male Characters'
maleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    maleCharacters.forEach(character => {
        let matchedDiv = allDivs.find((oneDiv) => {
            return oneDiv.firstChild.textContent === character.name
        })
        //matchedDiv.setAttribute("style", "display: none;")
        matchedDiv.className = 'animated infinite bounce delay-2s'
    })
});

let femaleButton = document.createElement('button')
femaleButton.textContent = 'Female Characters'
femaleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    femaleCharacters.forEach(character => {
        let matchedDiv = allDivs.find((oneDiv) => {
            return oneDiv.firstChild.textContent === character.name
        })
        //matchedDiv.setAttribute("style", "display: none;")
        matchedDiv.className = 'animated infinite bounce delay-2s;'
    })
});

let otherButton = document.createElement('button')
otherButton.textContent = 'Non-Gender Characters'
otherButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    otherCharacters.forEach(character => {
        let matchedDiv = allDivs.find((oneDiv) => {
            return oneDiv.firstChild.textContent === character.name
        })
        //matchedDiv.setAttribute("style", "display: none;")
        matchedDiv.className = 'animated infinite bounce delay-2s;'
    })
});

mainHeader.appendChild(maleButton)
mainHeader.appendChild(femaleButton)
mainHeader.appendChild(otherButton)
```

Comment: Before setting the animated class on the selected character, set all characters' animations off (matchedDiv.className='').

Comment: @seesharper could you explain that in greater detail in an answer?

Comment: Add complete html/css code too

Answer (score 0):

you need to use "this", if your buttons in a "div", try to write:

```
 this.parentElement.className = 'animated infinite bounce delay-2s;
```

instead of:

```
 matchedDiv.className = 'animated infinite bounce delay-2s;'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is crude because I don't have the full code, but roughly this:

```
const allDivs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div'))

const mainHeader = document.querySelector('header')

function clearAnimations() {
  [maleCharacters, femaleCharacters, otherCharacters].forEach(c => 
    c.forEach(character => allDivs.find((oneDiv) => 
      oneDiv.firstChild.textContent === character.name).className = '';
  });
}

let maleButton = document.createElement('button')
maleButton.textContent = 'Male Characters'
maleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearAnimations();
    maleCharacters.forEach(character => {
        let matchedDiv = allDivs.find((oneDiv) => {
            return oneDiv.firstChild.textContent === character.name
        })
        //matchedDiv.setAttribute("style", "display: none;")
        matchedDiv.className = 'animated infinite bounce delay-2s'
    })
});

let femaleButton = document.createElement('button')
femaleButton.textContent = 'Female Characters'
femaleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearAnimations();
    femaleCharacters.forEach(character => {
        let matchedDiv = allDivs.find((oneDiv) => {
            return oneDiv.firstChild.textContent === character.name
        })
        //matchedDiv.setAttribute("style", "display: none;")
        matchedDiv.className = 'animated infinite bounce delay-2s;'
    })
});

let otherButton = document.createElement('button')
otherButton.textContent = 'Non-Gender Characters'
otherButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clearAnimations();
    otherCharacters.forEach(character => {
        let matchedDiv = allDivs.find((oneDiv) => {
            return oneDiv.firstChild.textContent === character.name
        })
        //matchedDiv.setAttribute("style", "display: none;")
        matchedDiv.className = 'animated infinite bounce delay-2s;'
    })
});

mainHeader.appendChild(maleButton)
mainHeader.appendChild(femaleButton)
mainHeader.appendChild(otherButton)
```